# Python3.6 BeautifulSoup is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

my codes like below;

```
source_code = requests.get(kale_url_keys)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup("plain_text ")
```

or

```
r = requests.get(kale_url_keys)
html = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

I took error when I writing the "soup = BeautifulSoup(ANYTHING)" like below;

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: I see you have Python 3.6. Is `beautifulsoup4` updated to the most recent version?

Comment: Python 3.6. And yes I updated beautifulsoup4 .

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it with fresh Win7 @ amd64 installation and Python 3.6.0 :(

Comment: Please update your answer with output of `python --version`. UPDATE: it seems like you have to update your `requests` and `urllib3` to the latest version. You can do it with `pip`.

Comment: Python 3.6.1rc1 .
I have already updated requests, bs4.

Comment: I also updated urllib3 but I never used. Did I have to use it?

Comment: @Purgoufr is there any reason why you're using Python 3.6? It's still a release candidate and the problem could be simply caused by it.

Comment: there is no special case , I set up the program two days ago.

Comment: @ddnomad no, 3.6.0 is stable.

Comment: @alecxe your Python version contains 'rc' in it. It's release candidate -> not stable.

Comment: @ddnomad yes, I know what `rc` means - I mean that officially 3.6.0 is now stable. The OP though has the "rc" installed, in that sense you are right. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe yep, maybe I was not clear enough. OP's Python 3.6 is not stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do two things:

- install the latest **stable** [`Python 3.6.0`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/)
- update `beautifulsoup4` - make sure you update it in the correct Python 3.6.0 environment:

  ```
  pip3 install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade
  ```

Comment: I deleted all python version and then I set up Python 3.6.0 then I loaded all the libraries. And it' works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of getting using `request.urlopen` and instead of html.parser `lxml`
I'm on the same version of python as you are, everything working. Seems like you're getting errors from html.parser so using lxml parser should work

```
pip install lxml
```

or [Here for Linux or other installation methods.](http://lxml.de/installation.html)
Usage: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")`