# Import error with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have downloaded BeautifulSoup using `pip3 install beautifulsoup` and it worked fine.

But when I try `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` or `import BeautifulSoup`, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'` or `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'` depending on which line of code I use.

I have no idea what's wrong.  Why do I get the error?

Comment: Ok, so first things first.. Since you used `pip3` are you indeed using Python 3.x when trying the imports? If so, is it the same version of Python that runs when you run `Python3` via the command line?

Comment: Yes i am using python 3 (python 3.6 to be exact)

Comment: On macOS? If you open up a terminal and run `python3` what version do you see?

Comment: I am on windows 32 bit, how would i run python via the comand line

Comment: Ah, ok.. same question would apply though..

Comment: Try `pip36 install beautifulsoup` and try the imports again, just to be sure..

Comment: that doesnt work as  'pip36' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ok.. so if you are sure that pip3 is linked to python3.6 on your system, and that you are indeed running 3.6, try to update `requests` and `urllib3` via using pip3. As mentioned in the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42902917/4041795)

Comment: Also, see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42907729/4041795) helps you.

Comment: what line would you run to update those?

Comment: sorry have to go now

Comment: Ah, wait, found it [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) But I see Satish Garg just answered that..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pip3 install beautifulsoup` will install BeautifulSoup older version (`Beautiful Soup 3` to be precise).

You need to do `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` or `pip3 install bs4` to install `BeautifulSoup4`

and then you can just use it like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

You can refer to the [download page](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup) of `Beautiful Soup` for more understanding on this.

Comment: it no longer works, attempted to install again and got the error 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beatifulsoup (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for beatifulsoup'

Comment: Check your spelling for `beatifulsoup`. It is `beautifulsoup`

Comment: it still won't work, although the download starts for a bit, then it fails

Comment: what is the error after failing ? Is it permission denied ?

Comment: no... the error is 'Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\dnw13\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ikmdpwc0\BeautifulSoup\' but i have successfully installed bs4 can i use the same functions with that in python instead?

Comment: You can check, open the python shell and enter `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Don't mention it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and what solved it for me was to upgrade pip3.

Try this from [this thread comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710159/10260078)

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

And if that does not work, there is another way to upgrade it that I found [from this post](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5255#issuecomment-381702613)

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```