# Unable to install beautifulsoup4 in python on Mac Os

Tags: python-3.x, macos, beautifulsoup

I am trying to install `beautifulsoup4` in my mac using the following command:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

But I am getting this following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement beautifulsoup4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for beautifulsoup4
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OS High Sierra @StevenBlack

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install bs4`?

Comment: yep. didnt work @Jatimir

Comment: Try upgrading pip `pip3 install --upgrade pip`, you can also try installing with `python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`. Does `pip3 search beautifulsoup4` yields any results?

Comment: Please add your comment as answer. @Jatimir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update pip with `pip3 install --upgrade pip`. Now you should be able to install beautifulsoup `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`. If that fails try: `python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using a recent version of Debian or Ubuntu Linux, you can install Beautiful Soup with the system package manager:

`$ apt-get install python-bs4` (for Python 2)

`$ apt-get install python3-bs4` (for Python 3)

Or

you can install it with easy_install or pip.

```
$ easy_install beautifulsoup4

$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

If you are using Anaconda distribution, you can use this command.

```
conda install -c anaconda beautiful-soup
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using Mac OS. pip3 not able to find the version4

Comment: Please follow this link below, which will guide you to solve your problem https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1):

I tried upgrading pip3 with what Jatmir was suggesting, but it did not work for me. Finally, I found another way to upgrade it in this post https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5255#issuecomment-381702613

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my MacBook and I did below.(2018/September)

Update pip with

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Now you should be able to install beautifulsoup

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

If that fails try:

```
python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer and should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the tarball from [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/4.x/).

extract it, then run:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

if pip fails to work